# What's the canonical embedding of the globe category into Top?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

I'm looking at [this characterization of the globe category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/globe+category), and it's not clear to me how to think about it from an intuitive spatial standpoint. If each object $[n]$ corresponds to an $n$-sphere (ball?), then what are $\sigma$ and $\tau$?

Comment: The answer below is perfectly fine, but note that this is not just an intuitive thinking. This defines a functor $\mathbb G \to \mathbf{Top}$ that extends along the Yoneda embedding, yielding a geometric representation of any globular set $\widehat{\mathbb G} \to \mathbf{Top}$.

Comment: That's why I titled the question what I did :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the maps of the closed $n$-ball to the "northern" and "southern" hemispheres of the surface of the $(n+1)$-ball.